# C++ Non-Blocking ASIO Run

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, libcurl, nonblocking

I have created a series of functions that talk to Libcurl Multi and download files asynchronously via ASIO and Boost.

Obviously though when I call io_service.run it blocks my main thread when it is run. I have tried to make it non blocking but my app crashes.

I was wondering what is the simplest and best approach to running this in the background, in a non-blocking manner and have it call a call-back function when it is done (Like how you can do it in javascript).

So I could just go:

```
Runthisinthebackground( thingtodo, callback);
```

It would run the thingtodo and return the result to the callback. One thing though this must use Libraries such as boost that can run on devices with out C++ 11 as its for a mobile app running on Android and iOS

Comment: FWIW, both iOS and Android toolchains support C++11.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that :) Thanks for the heads up :) that makes things much easier :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `io_service` in another thread and post to it your functions:

```
asio::io_service io_service;
// give it some work, to prevent premature exit
shared_ptr<asio::io_service::work> work(new asio::io_service::work(io_service));
boost::thread t(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service);
t.detach();
//...
io_service.post(yourFunctor); // yourFunctor will be executed in the separate thread
```

Comment: Cheers :) it works just getting a bad memory error, I think I need to use that shared pointer to share my info

Comment: Thanks. With boost 1.50 I had to use `boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));`

Comment: @Gabriel Devillers According [to the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor), 1.50 already implements ctor with arguments.

Comment: I agree with that but gcc 5.4.0 (with C++0x) says `error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::asio::io_service*)`

Comment: @Gabriel Devillers Ok, I see. That's because `io_service::run` has multiple overloads, and `thread` ctor did not handle that.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers now it isn't working with  ```boost::bind```as well. I get bus error: 10.  I get segmentation fault if I do like @Igor did.